# testing if a DateTime was set

Tags: c#

I have an object model with a `DateTime`. It's not a nullable property so I can't write `if (SomeDate == null)` to test if it's been set or not. How do I test if a `DateTime` has been set or not?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *it's been set*?

Comment: @Oswald: that at some point in time, SomeDate = something has run.

Comment: Why can't you make it nullable a property?

Comment: @aquinas: because I want to be sure it's not null either; it HAS to be something.

Comment: But, wait a minute. The "something" (DateTime.MinValue as others are suggesting), is for all intents and purposes the same as null. Why does it HAVE to be something? Even if that something is a completely bogus date?

Comment: @aquinas: because the db needs a value

Comment: This is a bad approach. Db cant NEED a value if there might be a case when the value is not set, or was not set from start of something.

Comment: OK, let's keep backing up. :) Why does the *db* need a value? Is that something don't have control over?

Comment: @frenchie: Can you change the schema of your database such that this column is made nullable?

Comment: _When_ you write `if (SomeDate == null)` does it give you a compile-time warning that your check is meaningless, or that some code is unreachable? If not, blame Eric Lippert ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use

```
SomeDate == default(DateTime)
```

Note that this is not entirely safe. Calling `default` on a value type will return a value that might occur naturally in your application. For example, `default(int)` would give `0`; `default(bool)` gives `false`.

In the case of `DateTime`, the default is its [`MinValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx), which is 00:00:00.0000000, January 1, 0001. Although the likelihood of this date occurring naturally in your application is low, it would still be better practice to convert your field to `DateTime?` and check for null, since it would make your intention more legible.

Comment: What's the difference with the other answer?

Comment: Of course, it is entirely possible that someone said `SomeDate = default(DateTime)` in the past; this isn't a 100% guaranteed sure test that no one has set the property.

Comment: This is what I did in the bad old days, but with nullables, I'm not sure why anyone would need to do this.

Comment: @aquinas: I assumed that the OP is not able to modify the object model he's accessing, which makes the above a reasonable check.

Comment: @EricLippert: Valid point. However, I assume that the OP wants to check whether the field has been set to a semantically-reasonable value (rather than just set). In that case, having someone formerly perform `SomeDate = default(DateTime)` would be equivalent to "unsetting" it. Exactly the same argument holds for nullable types; a null value doesn't mean that the field was never set, but that it doesn't hold a value that needs to be considered.

Comment: I'll go with that answer. @EricLippert: I know what you mean about someone writing SomeDate = default(DateTime) but for me the test to default is enough.

Comment: @frenchie: What I mean is: You said you want a test to see if it has been set. Your test is to check to see if it is equal to the default, and if it is equal to the default, it's never been set. But what if it was set to some other value, and then set *back* to the default?  Now testing to see if it is the default value does *not* tell you if the property has never been set, because it *was* set in the past.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (datetime == DateTime.MinValue)
{
    //it was not set
}
```

Comment: What's the difference with the other answer?

Comment: @frenchie: There is no difference. `DateTime.MinValue`, `default(DateTime)` and `new DateTime()` are all ways to write "midnight, January 1st, 1AD".

Answer (score 2):

You could make SomeDate being *nullable*:

```
  DateTime? SomeDate = null;
  ...
  if (SomeDate == null) {
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In circumstances like you describe, I always explicitly initialize DateTimes to DateTime.MinValue (I don't know if the "default" value is guaranteed by the framework, or just an incidental side effect of variable allocation).    Then, in form / database logic, I always test for that value to see if it's been explicitly set.

As several others mentioned, this is a good candidate for using a nullable DateTime, but there is other logic that must be wrapped around that to convert it to a regular DateTime.

Comment: The default value is guaranteed by the framework. The `DateTime` struct does nothing more than giving a facade to a `long` that counts the amount of milisseconds since `DateTime.MinValue`. As a member of another type, that `long` will have a value of zero upon initialization, much like any other numeric variable.

Comment: @Renan Exactly, except it's not a milliseconds count but a "ticks" count, where one "tick" equals only 100 nanoseconds, or 0.1 microseconds.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen +1 because I didn't know that.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using a mocking framework - I personally use Rhino.Mocks. You can then create a mock object for whatever is having it's datetime set and directly assert that the property setter was called with a specific value, or with any value you expect.